# department wise employee details in specific format

Tags: sql, oracle10g

i have two tables employee and department

1.

```
create table department
(
    deptno int primary key,
    deptname varchar(20) not null,
    location varchar(50) not null
)
```

2.

```
create table employee
(
    empno int primary key,
    empname varchar(20) not null,
    salary number(12,2) not null,
    comission number(10,2) not null,
    designation varchar(20) not null,
    deptno int references department(deptno),
    constraints chk_sal check(salary>0)
)
```

if i want to print department wise employee details like

```
department name : <dept_name>
    <all employee details working in <dept_name>>
department name : <dept_name2>
    <all employee details working in <dept_name2>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you table structure, let's say you have data like this :

**DEPARTMENT :**

```
deptno          deptname        location
----------------------------------------------------------------
  101           Juniors         The screwed cubicle
  102           Seniors         The little less screwed cubicle
  103           Super Seniors   The screwers
```

**EMPLOYEE :**

```
empno           empname                     salary      comission   designation       deptno
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1         John Piledriven                 35000.00    2000.00     junior developer    101
  2         Ralph Chokeslam                 65000.00    3500.00     senior developer    102
  3         Ken Hurt                        40000.00    2000.00     junior developer    101
  4         Sue Yoo                         85000.00    3500.00     senior developer    102
  5         The One Who Shall Not Be Named  110000.00   5000.00     project manager     103
```

You can use the following query :

```
SELECT          dep.deptno,
                dep.deptname,
                dep.location,
                emp.empname,
                emp.salary,
                emp.comission,
                designation

FROM            department dep
LEFT JOIN       employee emp ON dep.deptno = emp.deptno
ORDER BY        dep.deptno
```

You can check this out here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c90e1/1

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: thank you but i want the solution like first i want to display department number than all employees working in it here department number is printed only once than employees working in it than second department number than employees working in it

Comment: @yash for that you might need to use CURSOR as you want to join results of 2 different queries. As your requirement says. In one line you want department and then you want employee details.. i.e. your select statement has 2 different things which is not possible in single SQL statement

Answer (score -2):

Query in mysql:

```
select e1.emp_id,e1.emp_name,d1.dept_id,d1.dept_name 
from employee e1,department d1,paydetail p1 
where e1.emp_id=p1.emp_id 
and d1.dept_id=p1.dept_id 
order by d1.dept_id;
```